# Solve $(A^TA)^{−1}(X+B^T)(C^{−1}B^{−1})^T =I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A, B, C \in M_n(\Bbb R)$ be invertible. Find $X \in M_n(\Bbb R)$ such that
$(A^TA)^{−1}(X+B^T)(C^{−1}B^{−1})^T =I$.
Express $X$ using no inverses and at most two transposes and show your choice of $X$
works.

I have no idea where to start. Can somebody give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$(C^{-1}B^{-1})^T=((BC)^{-1})^T=((BC)^T)^{-1}$$
so multiplying on the left and on right of the equality
$$(A^TA)^{−1}(X+B^T)(C^{−1}B^{−1})^T =I$$
by $A^TA$ and $(BC)^T$ respectively we find
$$X+B^T=A^TA(BC)^T=A^TAC^TB^T$$
and finally we have
$$X=A^TAC^TB^T-B^T=(BCA^TA-B)^T$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: let's take two matrices $P,\,Q$. Then $(PQ)^T=Q^TP^T$ and $(PQ)^{-1}= Q ^{-1} P ^{-1}$. Expand parantheses and express $X$ directly.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\forall A, B \in M_n(\Bbb R), (AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$ and $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$